# Li-po battery management system (BMS) design

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, bms

I am looking for advice about the design of a 3S LiPo battery which consist of three 3.7 V, 2500 mAh cells giving 11.1 V on its terminals.

[image: lipo battery (Cell)]

I have read many posts about Battery Management Systems to be able to design a PCB to meet the requirements of a good BMS.

For example, **the minimun value for discharge of a 1S 3.7 V cell is 3 V**.

The charging current is recommended to be the nominal current although the C rate of the battery is greather than 1C, so for this design it should be **2.5A** (given that it is a 2500 mAh battery).

The cut-off current which means the current value at which the charging process should finish is recommended to be 10% of the nominal current which corresponds to **0.25 A**.

Finally, the maximum voltage for each of the three cells is **4.1 V**.

Assuming the statements mentioned above are correct, the next step could be defining the requirements for the BMS itself.

I think a good design should consider overcharging protection, discharging protection, overcurrent protection, charging driver considering maximum allow voltage and cut off current, and load balancing of each of the three cells of the battery. I have read about different chips that offers the previous information as in the case of the [DW01A](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1901091236_PUOLOP-DW01A_C351410.pdf), [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf), and the [HY2212](https://www.hycontek.com/wp-content/uploads/DS-HY2212_EN.pdf).

Could somebody give me some tips to achieve my target? Also sharing some open source projects for reference such as GitHub projects. I know a little bit about PCB design so I can understand different things.

Comment: Using a purpose-built IC to handle the charge will be far easier and cheaper than any other method.  Pick one that matches the battery you're using with the features you want and the datasheet will tell you how to design a circuit around it.  If not, pick a different IC.

Comment: thank you so much vir, I will check for the information you mentioned above

Comment: Others say 4.2 max 3.2 min . But you can buy these charger/balancers <$15 What is best? Long life or max short term capacity or ?

Comment: So helpful comment, thanks Hoagie